# linux development i386 on amd64 machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, cross-compiling

I've a 64 bit machine with Ubuntu 14.04 that I use as development machine.
I need to develop both 32bit and 64bit application using gcc: so I installed `gcc-multilib` and I installed all needed dependencies using `sudo apt-get install dep-package-dev:i386` and building my projects using the `-m32` flags.

But building this way sucks because I cannot have both `dep-package-dev:i386` and `dep-package-dev`. Unfortunately it's not possible have both `amd64` and `i386` variant of a `*-dev` package.

At this point I've several choices:

1. Build all packages from scratch but this is not always possible... and I don't wanna shoot my self!
2. Use a VM...

Ironically it's easer build for armhf than for i686! Am I missing something? Which is the proper way to build both i386 and amd64 package for development?

Comment: I think all the `*-dev` packages contain are the C header files, which are cross-platform. Try installing just `libsomething`, `libsomething:i386`, and `libsomething-dev`

Comment: I think this is more a question of how you create the Debian packages (the `.deb` files).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It's not. I'm not interested of building `.deb` packages

Comment: Then why do you do `apt-get install` of your "package"? That seems to indicate that you build packages?

Comment: Often we need dependency for example of X11. And I need both i386 and amd64 variant. It will be crazy build from scratch x11 and all its dependencies in both variant

Comment: Thats a typical use case of vagrant imho. Did you give it a try? See: https://www.vagrantup.com/

Comment: So it's not *your* package that you try to install? The word "my" in the package name is kind of misleading. Then can you please elaborate on the problems you have with installing packages for both i386 and amd64? What errors (if any) do you get? Are you getting errors when installing the packages? When building? Are you missing to set some include or library path when building?

Comment: I've fixed it: I've changed from `my-package` to `dep-package`

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I'll give a try thank you for the suggest. Have you ever tried this way?

Comment: I haven't tried developing i86 software on x64, but I have installed i86 and x64 libraries simultaneously (in particular, WINE requires you to do so)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not so easy `*-dev` are more complicated to manage. I think I'll use vagrint